# Robinhood issue with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was writing a function to extract a stock's buy/sell/hold analyst ratings as follows:

```
pip install robin_stocks
import robin_stocks
robin_stocks.authentication.login(username=None, password=None, expiresIn=86400, scope='internal', by_sms=True, store_session=True, mfa_code=None)

def getRobinRating(symbol):
    buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')['num_buy_ratings']
    return buy

print(getRobinRating('NVCR'))
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-78-79c186ebe0bf>", line 9, in <module>
    print(getRobinRating('NVCR'))

  File "<ipython-input-78-79c186ebe0bf>", line 5, in getRobinRating
    buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')['num_buy_ratings']

KeyError: 'num_buy_ratings'
```

Strangely enough, if I just do this,

```
def getRobinRating(symbol):
    buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')
    return buy

print(getRobinRating('NVCR'))
```

Output:

```
{'summary': {'num_buy_ratings': 4, 'num_hold_ratings': 2, 'num_sell_ratings': 1}, 'ratings': [], 'instrument_id': '4d591f16-7f0a-4fe7-a369-5346a61c0dfb', 'ratings_published_at': None}
```

Why is it not able to get access to the dictionary in the former case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')` call is returning a dictionary with `summary` as the first key:

```
{'summary': 
    {'num_buy_ratings': 4, 
     'num_hold_ratings': 2, 
     'num_sell_ratings': 1}, 
 'ratings': [], 
 'instrument_id': '4d591f16-7f0a-4fe7-a369-5346a61c0dfb', 
 'ratings_published_at': None}
```

To access the inner dictionary, first access `summary`.

```
MyDict['summary']['num_buy_ratings']
```

Try this code:

```
buy = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings(symbol, info='summary')['summary']['num_buy_ratings']
```